# Custom control style binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

Is it possible to somehow select between the inner defined styles in CustomControl. I would like to use a depedency property which provides a key which sets the contoller style. Styles in the resource dictionaries x:Key-ed as the name of the xaml file. So how can I bind this key to the controller where I will use it to look like the style I defined inside the custom controller library.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxx.WPF.ButtonControl">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/xxx.WPF.ButtonControl;component/Themes/Base.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/xxx.WPF.ButtonControl;component/Themes/Flat.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Flat}"/>
    <!--<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Button}" IwouldLikeToBindMyDpHereToSelectFlatOrBaseStyle/>-->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your idea with a dependency property? You cannot define bindings for a `Style`.

Comment: Branching based on some condition decides which of 2 or more resource dictionaries to merge could be done in code. Datatriggers choose which datatemplate to use for content of a contentcontrol might be a better route to take. ( A button is a contentcontrol.  ) Custom controls are rarely a good plan. Especially not if you're new to wpf.  I think you need to explain more fully what you're trying to achieve if you want a good answer.